# In protobuf-net how do i deserialize an unknown type?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deserialize unknown type with protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675349/deserialize-unknown-type-with-protobuf-net)

In `protobuf-net`, how do I deserialize an unknown type?

Off the wire, I get a byte array but I don't know the type yet.

I was hoping to return object and test with `Object` `MyType` but the below doesn't work.

`object obj = Serializer.Deserialize<object>(new MemoryStream(cellUpdate.Payload));`