# Is of <T> allowed in a run-time ProtoBuf-net model?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I am using version 2 of ProtoBuf-net, and currently I'm geting the error "Unable to determine member: A"

Is it possible to create a run-time model for Protobuf-net when we use ClassOfType<T>?  If so, can anyone spot what I'm missing in the below code?

btw: this request is modelled off of [Deserialize unknown type with protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675349/deserialize-unknown-type-with-protobuf-net)  I could get a version of this going just fine... but they are using an abstract base class, not a generic class of T.

THIS IS A WORKING EXAMPLE (stuff that wasn't working is removed).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ProtoBuf;
using ProtoBuf.Meta;

namespace ProtoBufTestA2
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tester
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMsgBaseCreateModel()
        {
            var BM_SD = new Container<SomeDerived>();

            using (var o = BM_SD) {
                o.prop1 = 42;
                o.payload = new SomeDerived();
                using (var d = o.payload) {
                    d.SomeBaseProp = -42;
                    d.SomeDerivedProp = 62;
                }
            }

            var BM_SB = new Container<SomeBase>();
            using (var o = BM_SB) {
                o.prop1 = 42;
                o.payload = new SomeBase();
                using (var d = o.payload) {
                    d.SomeBaseProp = 84;
                }
            }
            var model = TypeModel.Create();

            model.Add(typeof(Container<SomeDerived>), true);  // BM_SD
            model.Add(typeof(Container<SomeBase>), true);  // BM_SB
            model.Add(typeof(SomeBase), true); // SB
            model.Add(typeof(SomeDerived), true);  // SD
            model[typeof(SomeBase)].AddSubType(50, typeof(SomeDerived)); // SD

            var ms = new MemoryStream();

            model.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, BM_SD, BM_SD.GetType(), ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);

            model.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, BM_SB, BM_SB.GetType(), ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var o1 = (Container<SomeDerived>)model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(
                ms
                , null
                , typeof(Container<SomeDerived>), PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);
            var o2 = (Container<SomeBase>)model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(
                ms
                , null
                , typeof(Container<SomeBase>), PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Container<T> : IDisposable
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int prop1 { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public T payload { get; set; }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class AnotherDerived : SomeDerived, IDisposable
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int AnotherDerivedProp { get; set; }
        public override void Dispose() { }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class SomeDerived : SomeBase, IDisposable
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int SomeDerivedProp { get; set; }

        public override void Dispose() { }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class SomeBase : IDisposable
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int SomeBaseProp { get; set; }

        public virtual void Dispose() { }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class NotInvolved : IDisposable
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int NotInvolvedProp { get; set; }
        public void Dispose() { }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class AlsoNotInvolved : IDisposable
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int AlsoNotInvolvedProp { get; set; }
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

*Request*

This is minor, but it'd be nice if

```
  (Container<SomeDerived>)model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(...)
```

could also be implemented like this

```
  model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Container<SomeDerived>>(...):
```

btw: I'm starting to dig into the protobuf-net implementation, and I'm starting to notice some interesting methods like this.  Something to come back to later I guess:

```
  public MetaType Add(int fieldNumber, string memberName, Type itemType, Type defaultType);
```

*Discussion:*

when I saw the way you could deserialize to an abstract base type in the link above, I thought, yes, that's closer to what was thinking. Could we deserialize to the open generic Container<> first, and then cast more specifically if we need to in different assemblies.  Maybe I'm getting mixed up a little here.

You could think of it in terms of Tupple<TBase,TPayload>.  Or a variation like Tupple<TBase,Lazy<TPayload>> maybe.  It's not that different to List<T>.  There are some TreeTypeThings<T> that I have too, but I don't need to serialize/deserialize them (yet).

I had a non-generic sequence working, so it isn't a show stopper.  My first implementation could be more efficient. I think I can do better on that with existing protobuf-net features though.

I like the cleaner generic way of working with these ideas.  Although I can get to the same destination manually, Generics make other things possible.

> re: clarification

everything can be defined ahead of time by the caller.  (btw: You've got me thinking about the run-time only scenario now, but no, I don't need that).

Comment: Re "Unable to determine member: A" - that is simply because *there is no member named `A`*, btw. Likewise `B`,`C`,`D` or `E`.

Comment: @Marc Gravell I'll look at that.  I *thought* that .Add(1, "A") created the label as well. It can't get that far.  Makes sense. Oops.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I got it all working okay in the end + changed the example code above to reflect this.  Thanks again.  Let's leave open generics as something to look at at another time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I *think* the question boils down to "can I use an open generic type as a template for a protobuf model", in which case the answer is "maybe". *At the moment*, it would see `BasicMsg<Foo>` and `BasicMsg<Bar>` as different types, and it would default to using the attribute type model, since it won't recognise them as being defined by `[typeof(BasicMsg<>)]`. If they *have* attributes, it'll probably work, but I don't think that was your intention, right?

This is an interesting scenario, and I'm open to discussion on it. However, one *particular* concern I'd have here is that the nature of generics in .NET means this would require runtime participation, i.e. `RuntimeTypeModel`. I don't think I could get it working on *pre-compiled* `TypeModel` without using `MakeGenericMethod` which I really want to avoid for both platform and performance reasons. But as a full-.NET runtime-only feature, it looks interesting.

(clarification on the above; if the caller could define all the `T` for `BasicMsg<T>` ahead of time, it becomes slightly more doable; then it really comes down to a model template metaphor)

Comment: thanks for taking a look.  Very kind.  Comments above rather than trying to fit them into a tweet x 3.

Comment: is it possible to serialize an object with a primitive type?  I've tried quite a few combinations in model.  btw: would you like this request as a new question?

Comment: @sgtz can you be more specific?

Comment: new question posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891415/serializing-a-dictionarystring-object-in-protobuf-net-fails

Comment: @sgtz if it is on-topic for this one, just edit it in and let me know

Comment: @MarcGravell hi, I know this question is really old but could you explain a bit about the difference between using `[ProtoMember(1, IsDynamic = true)]` (which enables full support for generics) and writing `type.AddField(1, "TestField"); type[1].DynamicType = true;`, which does not work? related question with example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535269/cant-serialize-generic-type-in-protobuf-net

Comment: @SteffenWinkler answered