# Can't serialize generic type

Tags: c#, generics, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize a generic type with protobuf-net, but protobuf-net says it can't serialize it.

As in:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CanSerialize(typeof(MyGenericClass<>))
```

returns true and

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CanSerialize(typeof(string))
```

returns true, too. But

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CanSerialize(typeof(MyGenericClass<string>)) //--> applies to all types that would return true when directly serialized as shown above for the string type
```

returns false. I guess I'm doing something wrong with how I add my `MyGenericClass` to the default runtimetype model. Since something like

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CanSerialize(typeof(List<Document>))
```

returns true.

My current code for adding the generic class:

```
var addedGenericType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(MyGenericClass<>), false);
addedGenericType.Add("Field1", "GenericField");
```

The error message says that there is no contract for the type I'm trying to serialize...which is obviously not true.

Here is an example demonstrating my problem and proofing that it should work:

```
using System;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace TestApplication
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public class TestClass<T>
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
        public T TestField { get; set; }

    }

    public class TestClass2<T>
    {
        public T TestField { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            DefineSecondClass();
            bool testResult = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CanSerialize(typeof(TestClass<string>));            
            bool testResult2 = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CanSerialize(typeof(TestClass2<string>));
            bool testResult3 = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CanSerialize(typeof(TestClass2<>));
            Console.WriteLine(testResult); // returns true
            Console.WriteLine(testResult2); // returns false
            Console.WriteLine(testResult3); // returns true
        }

        private void DefineSecondClass()
        {
            var type = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(TestClass2<>), false);
            type.AddField(1, "TestField");
            type[1].DynamicType = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As a follow up (and to clarify my comments) let's take this code:

using System;
    using ProtoBuf;

```
namespace TestApplication
{        

    public class TestClass<T>
    {
        public T TestField { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComplexType
    {
        public string SomeFieldA{get; set;}
        public int SomeFieldB{get; set;}
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            DefineComplexType();
            // how to add the type TestClass<ComplexType> to the RuntimeTypeModel without calling
            // DefineComplexType() again?
        }

        private void DefineComplexType()
        {
            var type = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ComplexType), false);
            type.AddField(1, "SomeFieldA");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note: I would be very careful using `DynamicType` here; that should really only be used as a last ditch approach to serializing things like `object` - it is not the recommended or "normal" approach, and has some major caveats. There is **certainly** no need to use it with `<string>`.

Comment: @MarcGravell  you mean that it should also work without setting `IsDynamic` to true?

Comment: in the example shown? absolutely; setting `IsDynamic` / `DynamicType` should **not** be a common thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing:

```
var type = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(
    typeof(TestClass2<>), false);
type.AddField(1, "TestField");
type[1].DynamicType = true;
```

You have configured the `TestClass2<>` type. Which is great, but... you never use that type. In fact, it cannot be used - `Add` should probably throw an error. You use `TestClass<string>` which to most intents and purposes is a completely separate `Type` instance.

I guess the logic here is that: a closed generic type should inherit its configuration from the generic type definition, if the generic type definition is configured. I can see the logic of that, but: that is not currently implemented, and like everything else would require specification, design, implementation, testing, support and documentation. Which takes time.

For today: if you want to work with `TestClass2<string>`, you should *configure* `TestClass2<string>`.

Note that when using attributes, attributes are inherently present on the closed types; so it is the case that `TestClass1<string>.TestField` has the `[ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]` marker.

I suspect that if you do:

```
private void DefineSecondClass()
{
    var type = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(
        typeof(TestClass2<string>), false);
    type.AddField(1, "TestField");
    type[1].DynamicType = true;
}
```

then it will work fine.

Comment: to your edit: Yes, that does work. Would it be possible to add the `TestClass<SomeComplexTypeWithFields>` to the RuntimeTypeModel without having to re-define all fields of `SomeComplexTypeWithFields` (`SomeComplexTypeWithFields` would already be known to ProtoBuf's RuntimeTypeModel)?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I don't understand: the fields of `SomeComplexTypeWithFields` and `TestClass<SomeComplexTypeWithFields>` are completely unrelated; I'm not sure what you mean by "having to re-define all fields" here.

Comment: If you look at my TestClass2, you'll see that it contains the `TestField` which has the generic type. Now, if I use `SomeComplexTypeWithFields` as the argument for the generic type like this `TestClass2<SomeComplexTypeWithFields>` I want ProtoBuf to serialize the fields contained in `SomeComplexTypeWithFields` without having to add the type/fields to the `RuntimeTypeModel` a second time. Of course I'll have to add `TestField` as the field to serialize, but that's not a problem.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler What second time? Does `SomeComplexTypeWithFields` have attributes? When was `SomeComplexTypeWithFields` configured a first time?

Comment: I'm assuming that `SomeComplexTypeWithFields` was configured via `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(...)` including at least some of the fields defined inside the type.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler re your "how to add"; just `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(TestClass<ComplexType>), false).Add("TestField");`. It isn't clear to me why you think you would need to call `DefineComplexType()` again...

Comment: Because in a previous test, that didn't work. Maybe I did something different/wrong.