# How do I change my previously saved List type to serialize into an Array type

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

Previously, we serialized a property as a `List<byte>`
Now we want to change it to be a `byte[]`.
It was out understanding that you should be able to swap out collection types freely between version but we get a `ProtoBuf.ProtoException`

```
[TestFixture, Category("Framework")]
class CollectionTypeChange 
{
    [Test]
    public void TestRoundTrip()
    {
        var bytes = new List<byte>() {1,2,4};
        var a = new ArrayHolder(bytes);

        var aCopy = Deserialize<ArrayHolder>(Serialize(a));

        //Passes
        Assert.That(aCopy.CollectionOfBytes, Is.EquivalentTo(a.CollectionOfBytes));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestChangeArrayToList()
    {
        var bytes = new List<byte>() { 1, 2, 4 };
        var a = new ArrayHolder(bytes);

        var aCopy = Deserialize<ListHolder>(Serialize(a));

        //Passes
        Assert.That(aCopy.CollectionOfBytes, Is.EquivalentTo(a.CollectionOfBytes));
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestChangeListToArray()
    {
        var bytes = new List<byte>() { 1, 2, 4 };
        var a = new ListHolder(bytes);

        //Throws: ProtoBuf.ProtoException : Invalid wire-type; this usually means you have over-written a file without truncating or setting the length; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2152978/23354
        var aCopy = Deserialize<ArrayHolder>(Serialize(a));

        Assert.That(aCopy.CollectionOfBytes, Is.EquivalentTo(a.CollectionOfBytes));
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
internal class ArrayHolder
{
    private ArrayHolder()
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = new byte[0] {};
    }

    internal ArrayHolder(IEnumerable<byte> bytesToUse )
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = bytesToUse.ToArray();
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte[] CollectionOfBytes { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
internal class ListHolder
{
    private ListHolder()
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = new List<byte>();
    }

    internal ListHolder(IEnumerable<byte> bytesToUse)
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = bytesToUse.ToList();
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<byte> CollectionOfBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a special thing about arrays, or bytes that means this doesn't work like we expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a problem specifically with `byte[]` properties.  If I change the property types to `int []` and `List<int>` the behavior is not reproducible.  The problem arises from the fact that there are two ways to encode an array in a Protocol Buffer: as repeated key/value pairs or ["packed"](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#packed-repeated-fields) as a single key with a length-delimited block of values.

For byte arrays, protobuf-net uses a special serializer, [`BlobSerializer`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Serializers/BlobSerializer.cs), which simply writes the byte array length then block-copies the contents into the output buffer as a packed repeated field.  It does the reverse operation when reading -- not handling the case when the data is actually in repeated key/value format.

On the other hand, `List<byte>` is serialized using the general-purpose [`ListDecorator`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Serializers/ListDecorator.cs).  Its `Read()` method tests to see the format currently in the input buffer and reads it appropriately -- either packed or unpacked.  Its `Write()` method, however, writes the byte array unpacked by default.  Subsequently, when reading the buffer into a `byte []` array, `BlobSerializer` throws an exception because the format is not as expected.  Arguably this is a bug with protobuf-net's `BlobSerializer`.

<s>There is, however, a straightforward workaround: state that the `List<byte>` should be serialized in packed format by setting `IsPacked = true`:</s>

```
[ProtoContract]
internal class ListHolder
{
    private ListHolder()
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = new List<byte>();
    }

    internal ListHolder(IEnumerable<byte> bytesToUse)
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = bytesToUse.ToList();
    }

    [ProtoMember(1, IsPacked = true)]
    public List<byte> CollectionOfBytes { get; set; }
}
```

This should be a more compact representation for your list of bytes as well.

Unfortunately, the above workaround fails when the byte collection contains bytes with the *high bit* set.  Protobuf-net serializes a packed `List<byte>` as a length-delimited sequence of [Base 128 Varints](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints).  Thus when a byte with its high bit set is serialized, it is encoded as two bytes.  On the other hand a `byte []` member is serialized like a string as a [length-delimited sequence of raw bytes](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#strings).  Thus one byte in the byte array is always encoded as byte in the encoding - which is incompatible with the encoding for `List<byte>`.

As a workaround, one could use a private surrogate `List<byte>` property in the `ArrayHolder` type:

```
[ProtoContract]
internal class ArrayHolder
{
    private ArrayHolder()
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = new byte[0] { };
    }

    internal ArrayHolder(IEnumerable<byte> bytesToUse)
    {
        CollectionOfBytes = bytesToUse.ToArray();
    }

    [ProtoIgnore]
    public byte[] CollectionOfBytes { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]
    List<byte> ListOfBytes
    {
        get
        {
            if (CollectionOfBytes == null)
                return null;
            return new List<byte>(CollectionOfBytes);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            CollectionOfBytes = value.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qULhot).

Alternatively, one could replace the `ArrayHolder` with a `ListHolder` during (de)serialization by using [`MetaType.SetSurrogate()`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L1296) as shown for instance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7046868/3744182).